# Deploying from eclipse to glassfish 4.1.2 - Missing classes

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

1.) It is possible to export a fully-functional war-file from eclipse.

2.) Running the application from eclipse doesn't work, mainly because the server can't find injected classes.
I browsed ../domain1/eclipseApps/myApp/WEB-INF and folder "./classes" only contains folders but not a single file. 
E.g. Folder "./classes/my/package/" exists. File "./classes/my/package/myClass.class" is missing.

Sometimes I can solve the problem by stopping the server, clean the server, clean&build the project, restarting eclipse and adding the application to the server. This works 1 out of 10 times and isn't long lasting.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What's your build configuration? Is this a maven project?

Comment: Yes. It is a maven project. Export a war-file works and running maven (clean install) also creates a working war-file.

Answer (score 0):

You can a few things here.

1. Project > Clean...
2. Make sure that "Build automatically" is checked.
3. Make sure that the project is "synchronized" in the server view. If it shows "publish" try hitting the republish (ctrl + alt + p) button.
4. Check if there is a newer version of your GF adapter
5. Try upgrading your eclipse version